# Best way to produce a graph similar to one generated by Maple

Tags: plot, graphs, maple2e

I wish to produce the following graph from Maple in my Latex document, here is my Maple code:

```
p := x -> (6-(10/3)*sqrt(Pi))*x^4+((79/3)*sqrt(Pi)-142/3)*x^3+(269/2-(224/3)*sqrt(Pi))*x^2+(-973/6+(269/3)*sqrt(Pi))*x+70-38*sqrt(Pi):
plot([GAMMA(x), p(x)], x = 1..3, legend = [GAMMA(x), P(x)]);
```

I'm fairly new to Latex and so I am not aware of the different packages that can be used for plotting graphs.

Comment: Why not export it from Maple as an eps (encapsulated postscript) graphic and then import it using `\includegraphics`?

Comment: You can also use `pgfplots`, which comes with a tutorial in the latest version. It can calculate, but not as fancy as Maple. But you could export your `x` and `y` data points from Maple, just plotting it with pgfplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can find plenty of plot examples on this site,
produced with different graphic systems available in `LaTeX`.
This example uses `Asymptote`.

```
% dplot.tex :
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
size(8cm);
import graph;
import fontsize;
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
real xmin=1,xmax=3;
real ymin=0.8,ymax=2.2;
pen ppen=black+0.8bp+dashed;
pen gpen=lightblue+1.4bp;
real sqrtpi=sqrt(pi);
real[] a={70-38*sqrtpi, -973/6+(269/3)*sqrtpi, 
269/2-(224/3)*sqrtpi, (79/3)*sqrtpi-142/3, 6-(10/3)*sqrtpi};

real p(real x){return x*(x*(x*(x*a[4]+a[3])+a[2])+a[1])+a[0];}

draw(graph(gamma,xmin,xmax),gpen,legend="$\Gamma(x)$");
draw(graph(p,xmin,xmax),ppen,legend="$P(x)$");

xaxis("$x$",YEquals(ymin),xmin,xmax,RightTicks(Step=0.2,step=0.04));
yaxis("$y$",XEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,LeftTicks(Step=0.2,step=0.04));

add(legend(nullpen),point(N),20S,UnFill);
\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To get the output `gplot.pdf`, run `pdflatex gplot.tex` first 
(the `gplot-1.asy` file will be generated among other things),
then run `asy gplot-*.asy` and then run `pdflatex gplot.tex` again.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. The plot looks really good in your answer.